# Insufficient Privileges right after I updated a Lead

Tags: leads, update

I have an app that we developed for our client. The purpose of this app is to update `Lead` objects in SalesForce.

After firing `https://eu*.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Lead/00QLeadID` with a simple JSON of `{"status": "Qualified"}`, the app receives `201` HTTP code. But the user, who fired this, got all his privileges revoked on the said `Lead`. Sadly, this happens only on Production.

I lack the info if same happens during inserts. We do not insert, we only update so far.

Comment: Are you using assignment rules? Do you have workflow rules that change ownership? It might just be a difference between environments.

Comment: Do they have an update trigger that changes the Lead Owner?

Comment: Thanx for suggestions, this will probably take time to get those answers from their admins

Comment: who is the running user for the  REST API request? An integration user or the user who can't access the Lead.

Comment: @cropredy the one who can access the lead first, but can't access the lead afterforwards